# dense_rank() function equivalent in access database

Tags: sql, ms-access

As we have dense_rank function in sql server do we any equivalent in access?

I have a table

```
employee_name employee_address
RON           23-B, TORONTO
PETER         15-C, NY
TED           23-C, LONDON
RON           23-B, TORONTO
```

I have to add new column to this table as follows:

```
employee_name employee_address   employee_no
RON           23-B, TORONTO      1
PETER         15-C, NY           2
TED           23-C, LONDON       3
RON           23-B, TORONTO      1
```

Comment: No, Access does not have any windowed functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I assume you want to *port* in Access a SQL Server query like this:

`SELECT *
    ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY employee_name, employee_address) AS DenseRank
FROM Employee`.

- The main idea is to generate a list with distinct `employee_name & employee_address` values and then we generate row numbers without gaps for every distinct tuple. At final step, we make a JOIN between the initial data set (Employee table) and the last data set (which has row numbers for every distinct `employee_name & employee_address` tuple).

**Solution 1**

*Query0*

`CREATE TABLE Employee
(
    employee_id INT PRIMARY KEY
    ,employee_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
    ,employee_address VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);`

*Query1*

`INSERT INTO    Employee (employee_id, employee_name, employee_address)
VALUES  (1,'RON','23-B, TORONTO');`

*Query2*

`INSERT INTO    Employee (employee_id, employee_name, employee_address)
VALUES  (2,'PETER','15-C, NY');`

*Query3*

`INSERT INTO    Employee (employee_id, employee_name, employee_address)
VALUES  (3,'TED','23-C, LONDON');`

*Query4*

`INSERT INTO    Employee (employee_id, employee_name, employee_address)
VALUES  (4,'SORIN','09-S, VASCAUTI');`

*Query5*

`INSERT INTO    Employee (employee_id, employee_name, employee_address)
VALUES  (5,'RON','23-B, TORONTO');`

*Query6*

`INSERT INTO    Employee (employee_id, employee_name, employee_address)
VALUES  (6,'PETER','15-C, NY');`

*Query7*

`INSERT INTO    Employee (employee_id, employee_name, employee_address)
VALUES  (7,'SORIN','09-S, VASCAUTI');`

*Query8*

`INSERT INTO    Employee (employee_id, employee_name, employee_address)
VALUES  (8,'PETER','15-C, NY');`

So, the Employee content will be:

```
employee_id employee_name                                                                                        employee_address
----------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           RON                                                                                                  23-B, TORONTO
2           PETER                                                                                                15-C, NY
3           TED                                                                                                  23-C, LONDON
4           SORIN                                                                                                09-S, VASCAUTI
5           RON                                                                                                  23-B, TORONTO
6           PETER                                                                                                15-C, NY
7           SORIN                                                                                                09-S, VASCAUTI
8           PETER                                                                                                15-C, NY
```

*Query9* We generate row numbers for every `employee_name & employee_address` tuple

```
CREATE TABLE TmpEmployee
(
    rownumber COUNTER(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,employee_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
    ,employee_address VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
```

(`COUNTER(1,1)` is Access/SQL AutoNumber data type; before every Query10 execution you need to recreate TmpEmployee table or you need to compact Access DB to reset `rownumber` counter to 1) and

*Query10*

```
INSERT INTO TmpEmployee (employee_name, employee_address)
SELECT   e.employee_name, e.employee_address
        FROM     Employee e
        GROUP BY e.employee_name, e.employee_address
```

Results:

```
rownumber   employee_name                                                                                        employee_address
----------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           PETER                                                                                                15-C, NY
2           RON                                                                                                  23-B, TORONTO
3           SORIN                                                                                                09-S, VASCAUTI
4           TED                                                                                                  23-C, LONDON
```

*Query11* The final results:

```
SELECT e.*, t.RowNumber AS DenseRank
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN TmpEmployee t ON e.employee_name = t.employee_name AND e.employee_address = t.employee_address
ORDER BY e.employee_name, e.employee_address
```

Results:

```
2   PETER   15-C, NY    1
6   PETER   15-C, NY    1
8   PETER   15-C, NY    1
5   RON 23-B, TORONTO   2
1   RON 23-B, TORONTO   2
4   SORIN   09-S, VASCAUTI  3
7   SORIN   09-S, VASCAUTI  3
3   TED 23-C, LONDON    4
```

**Solution 2**
*Query9* The final results:

```
SELECT   e.*, c.RowNumber
FROM     Employee e INNER JOIN
(
SELECT  a.employee_name, a.employee_address, COUNT(b.employee_name) AS RowNumber
        FROM
    (
        SELECT   e.employee_name, e.employee_address
        FROM     Employee e
        GROUP BY e.employee_name, e.employee_address
    ) a,
    (
        SELECT  e.employee_name, e.employee_address
        FROM     Employee e
        GROUP BY e.employee_name, e.employee_address
    ) b 
WHERE a.employee_name > b.employee_name  OR a.employee_name = b.employee_name AND a.employee_address >= b.employee_address 
    GROUP BY a.employee_name, a.employee_address
) c ON e.employee_name = c.employee_name AND e.employee_address = c.employee_address
ORDER BY c.employee_name, c.employee_address
```

Comment: You can reset the counter using SQL DDL in [ANSI-92 Query mode](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/about-ansi-sql-query-mode-mdb-HP003070483.aspx) e.g. `ALTER TABLE TmpEmployee ALTER COLUMN rownumber COUNTER(1,1);`